# I am extending a pug layout(parent) to another pug layout(child).I am getting an error 'unexpected token:indent' from the parent layout

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pug

This file name is layout.pug(parent):

```
 doctype html 
 html
   head
     title knowledgebase
   body 
     block content     
     br
     hr
     footer
       p Copyright &copy; 2018
```

And this file name is index.pug(child):

```
extends layout
block content
  h1 articles
  h1 #{title}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought everything was good with your code, then I looked closely at what was pasted here.

If inspect the code in layout.pug you'll see that there's a leading space on every line.  Make sure that `doctype html` and `html` (which are your root elements in the parent template) have ZERO spaces at the start of the line.

Otherwise your code looks good and should work as expected.